# Webpage fails to load as soon as I use bindParam with PDO

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

I'm working on a system that uses a MS Access database that I'm querying using PDO. What I've build works when I run it using a basic XAMPP installation.

Once I uploaded it to the webserver I noticed that it wasn't working, the page simply doesn't load, no error logs or anything. I tried to troubleshoot it and found that as soon as I comment out the bindParam line the script actually runs and shows that I have an incorrect field count.

I made a reduced test case that has the same behaviour:

```
try {

  $db = new PDO("odbc:{$database};UID={$user};PWD={$password};charset=utf8;");

  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer.id = :id");

  $id = NULL;

  $select->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  $id = 1;

  $select->execute();

  $result = $select->fetchAll();

  foreach ( $result as $row ) {

    var_dump ( $row );
    echo '<br>';

  }

} catch(PDOException $e){

  echo "The query has failed: " . $e->getMessage();

  die();

}
```

As soon as I comment out `$select->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` the script actually runs and gives me an error which is logical.

I've done some basic troubleshooting like checking versions of PHP etc. which I found no differences in. I've looked for a solution for a couple of days already with no luck.

Errors I've gotten after enabling `error_reporting(E_ALL);`:

```
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32-application.
in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32-application.
in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` / `display_errors` in conjunction to probing for runtime exceptions.

Comment: @mario Doing that gave me at least some output to the logs. Looking into the error message now, hopefully finding a solution.

Comment: Is this a Windows or a Linux server?

Comment: @hakre It's a windows server

Comment: check odbc library versions. and pdo driver and library versions. both on your xampp setup as well as on server.

Comment: Would you edit into your question the errors you are now seeing? (They are best in the question rather than in the comments).